# For loop value in Promise.then() inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a question about promise.then() inside a for loop in node.js.

For a code like this:

```js
const arrayObject = [
  {
    id: 1234,
    toto: 'abc'
  },
  {
    id: 5678,
    toto: 'def'
  },
  {
    id: 910,
    toto: 'ghi'
  },
]
const finalArray = []
let promiseArray = []
for (let singleObject of arrayObject) {
    promiseArray.push(
        Promise.function(...).then(res => {
            if (res === true) {
                finalArray.push(singleObject)
            }
        })
    )
}
await Promise.all(promiseArray)
```

If the singleObject before the promise is 'id: 1234', will the singleObject in the promise is the same ?

I know that with tests I have done it is but I can't find any documentation/example stating that the singleObject in the promise.then will be the same as the singleObject before the promise.

Does the singleObject in the promise.then  is always in the same scope as the singleObject before the promise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both variables contain references to the same object. It has nothing to do with `Promise.then`. It's the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) of the arrow function

```
res => { if (res === true) { finalArray.push(singleObject) } }
```

> A **closure** is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the **lexical environment**). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function's scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

Even the global scope is part of the [closure scope chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#closure_scope_chain):

> Every closure has three scopes:
>
> - Local Scope (Own scope)
> - Outer Functions Scope
> - Global Scope

Comment: Thank you ! I thought that the Promise change something about that but it's not as you said. Thanks for this link to the documentation I can understand a little bit more

Answer (score -2):

Not 100% sure, but I'd say the `singleObject` is indeed the same before and after. I believe it might be a reference to the original object ?
The way to check that would be to modify one of the objects in `arrayObject`, and then print both `arrayObject` and `finalArray`, check if the object you modified is modified in both.

Comment: From the downvotes it seems like I'm wrong.
Can anyone elaborate so I can learn?

Looking at @jabaa's answer, I was on the right path but I must have missed something...